# sqoop import is not identifying mysql tables showing ClassNotFountException Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have a mysql table "customers" and tried importing data from mysql to hdfs location using sqoop import. Below are the versions I installed on my machine:
sqoop version: 1.4.6
hive version: 2.3.0
Hadoop version: 2.8.1

Sqoop import Command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/localdb --username root --password mnbv@1234 --table customers -m 1 --target-dir /user/hduser/sqoop_import/customers1/
```

and showing below ClassNotFountException:

```
Tue Oct 31 09:57:21 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.17/10/31 09:57:21 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation             17/10/31 09:57:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 1=1 AND 1=1 
17/10/31 09:57:21 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete. 
17/10/31 09:57:22 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1437452057_0001java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class customers not found 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:549)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class customers not found at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2216) 
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:237)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:263)     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:515)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:758)     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class customers not found     at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2122)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2214)
... 12 more
17/10/31 09:57:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1437452057_0001 running in uber mode : false  17/10/31 09:57:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/10/31 09:57:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1437452057_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA  17/10/31 09:57:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
17/10/31 09:57:22 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead  17/10/31 09:57:22 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 4.105 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
17/10/31 09:57:22 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead  17/10/31 09:57:22 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
17/10/31 09:57:22 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

But when I tried listing tables using sqoop command it is working fine and showing customers table.
Sqoop command:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/localdb --username root --password mnbv@1234;
```

Output is displayed properly as shown:

```
17/10/31 10:07:09 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL  streaming resultset.          
Tue Oct 31 10:07:09 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+,  5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not  using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true  and provide truststore for server certificate verification.                                                                                                customers
```

what might be the issue, why sqoop import from table is not recognizing the table from mysql. Kindly help me on the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 
`--bindir`
option and point to your current working directory.Under the --bindir option give the path of $SQOOP_HOME/lib

Sorry for late reply.**Updating the Answer as per latest comment**.Please check the below:

- The jar file needs to checked while the sqoop process is running in
  the cmd: `Writing jar file:/tmp/sqoop.../*.jar`
- Use the import command: `sqoop import -fs local
  -jt local -libjars /tmp/..../*.jar --connect "jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop" --username <>--password <>--table
  customers`
- Verify the generated Java file for sqoop import. It should have the
  same name as the table you are importing normally. `sqoop codegen
  --connect <""> --username <> --password <> --table customers`

Hope this helps!

Comment: 17/11/01 09:32:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local349901698_0001 running in uber mode : false
17/11/01 09:32:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/11/01 09:32:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local349901698_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
17/11/01 09:32:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
 Map-Reduce Framework
  Map input records=2
  Map output records=2
Input split bytes=87
  Spilled Records=0
  Failed Shuffles=0
  Merged Map outputs=0
 File Input Format Counters 
  Bytes Read=0
 File Output Format Counters 
  Bytes Written=164

Comment: 17/11/01 09:32:24 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
17/11/01 09:32:24 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 3.8506 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
17/11/01 09:32:24 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 2 records.
17/11/01 09:32:24 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!     Could not find the issue pls help on the same.